# Need to prevent entry of "U+3000" full-width Japanese spaces in Word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting, character

**Short version:**
So I have a Word doc with very specific formatting guidelines, into which Japanese users have to input text. Despite being specifically told not to, instead of using "tab" to create indents, they will very often use full-width Japanese spaces (U+3000). I want to somehow prevent the entry of this character to avoid having to reformat.

**Long version:**
We send out Japanese/English-language script templates for Japanese users to input their own dialogue into. They will often ignore the formatting of the script, using hard returns and full-width spaces to hack-format the doc (very common practice among Japanese Word users). This leads to unnecessary time spent on re-formatting. As I see it I have three options:

1. Prevent the entry of undesired characters, by blocking the character
   or setting up a dialogue box every time it is used.
2. Automate a dialogue box to pop up when the document is saved, displaying a message to users to make sure no undesired characters were used.
3. Create a macro to auto-replace undesired characters on my end.

**Any suggestions? Help is very much appreciated.**

Comment: Could you please provide screenshots (with hidden formatting symbols) of required formatting and what you actually get? IMO users will not be happy with annoying dialogs. You may display something like popup, which doesn't block typing, after each instant auto replacement. May be the better solution is to use another formatting features like table or form, so that users should not be concerned with indents creation at all.